# Xcode Auto Completion Types

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

For some reason, my autocompletion "mode/type" has switched.

**Wrong autocompletion type:**

[image]

as of now, it's in "code snippet" where it's recommending purely swift syntax and I can't figure out how to take it back to the other mode, the suggestion mode.

**Working version:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Turns out, quitting Xcode and reopening it does the trick :)